# Highlight a cell with a color when an image within the cell is clicked in a data table

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, table, image-formula

I have a VF page with a datatable in which an image or a flag is placed in a cell for identification. when the flag or image is clicked using mouse event, the particular cell's background color which contains the image should be changed to a given color. Kindly help me by providing a solution or sample code if any.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?Are you looking for solution just based on javascript or jquery or you are looking for solution with native sfdc visualforce tags?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to implement to use jQuery. It will take the clicked element (`td` element of the table) and set the background color to the parent element ('tr'). But first it will remove the background color from all tr's of the table:

```
<script>
    function setColor(elem){
        jQuery('[id$=myTable] tr').css('backgroundColor','');
        jQuery(elem).parent().css('backgroundColor','red');
    }
</script>

<apex:dataTable value="{!list1}" var="item" rules="rows" frame="above below" id="myTable">
    <apex:column value="{!item.id}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!item.name}" onclick="setColor(this);"/>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Result:

[image]